# how do i achieve this type of edit text with xml

Tags: java, android

[edit text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxH6n.png)

I am a complete newbie to android. I am currently working on a note app and i need help in achieving this type of edit text view with xml. The references i av looked upon so far didnt appear clear to me.

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // Gets the number of lines of text in the View.
        int count = getLineCount();

        // Gets the global Rect and Paint objects
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;

        /*
         * Draws one line in the rectangle for every line of text in the EditText
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            // Gets the baseline coordinates for the current line of text
            int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);

            /*
             * Draws a line in the background from the left of the rectangle to the right,
             * at a vertical position one dip below the baseline, using the "paint" object
             * for details.
             */
            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        }

        // Finishes up by calling the parent method
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Comment: why not use an image and have the background of the edit text be that drawable?

Comment: how do i come up with the multiple horizontal lines then?

Comment: i thought you meant the top part.... but the bottom..... i would have to assume its a background that is repeated on Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that extends an EditText

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000); //change this to your color
    }

    /**
     * This is called to draw the LinedEditText object
     * @param canvas The canvas on which the background is drawn.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        int curHeight = 0;
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);
        for (curHeight = baseline + 1; curHeight < height;
             curHeight += getLineHeight())
        {
            canvas.drawLine(r.left, curHeight, r.right, curHeight, paint);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

In your XML

```
<your.package.name.LinedEditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:minLines="10"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionNone"/>
```

[image]

Comment: wow. helpful content. but how do i achieve the top level edit text that looks like a toolbar?

Comment: i dont need you to show me the code. its just the idea i need to know

Comment: if you have any experience with xml, i think its pretty easy to do that....create a relative layout, inside of the relative layout, put your exit text and an image...